# Restructuring program to meet certain criteria, could use some advice

Tags: c#, variables, methods, scope

(sorry if I'm asking too many questions)

Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to restructure the program I've written to meet criteria. I want to break it apart into different methods to make it easier to read, but I'm having trouble getting the different methods to play with each other (eg. variables scope errors).

Right now my code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scoring {
class Program {

    static int highOccurrence = 0;
    static int lowOccurrence = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] scores = { 4, 7, 9, 3, 8, 6 };


        findScore(scores);
        ExitProgram();
    }


    static int findOccurrence(int[] scores) { //find the number of times a high/low occurs

        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++) {

            if (low == scores[i]) {

                lowOccurrence++;
                //record number of time slow occurs
            }

            if (high == scores[i]) {


                highOccurrence++;

                //record number of times high occurs
            }

            }

    }

    static int findScore(int[] scores) {


        int[] arrofNormal = new int[scores.Length];

        int low = scores[0];
        int high = scores[0];
        int total = 0;


        //int highOccurrence = 0;
        //int lowOccurrence = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++) {

           // if (low == scores[i]) {

           //     lowOccurrence++;
           //     //record number of time slow occurs
           // }

           // if (high == scores[i]) {


           //     highOccurrence++;

           //     //record number of times high occurs
           // }

            if (low > scores[i]) {

                low = scores[i];


            } //record lowest value


            if (high < scores[i]) {

                high = scores[i];

                //record highest value
            }


        }

        for (int x = 0; x < scores.Length; x++) {

            if (scores[x] != low && scores[x] != high) {

                arrofNormal[x] = scores[x];
                 //provides the total of the scores (not including the high and the low) 
            }

            total += arrofNormal[x];

        }

        if (highOccurrence > 1) { //if there is more than 1 high (or 1 low) it is added once into the total

            total += high;

            if (lowOccurrence > 1) {

                total += low;
            }
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Sum = " + total);



        return total; //remove not all code paths return.. error


    }



    static void ExitProgram() {
        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit program: ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }//end ExitProgram

}
}
```

As you can see its still very much a work on progress. I get error such as "variable name" is does not exist in current context", I know this is a scope error, how can I fix it? Advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How about: You take care of formatting your question properly, without so many spaces, so whomever tries to help you don't need to waste time scrolling ?  
There are whole pages to how to ask a good question, and what is proper etiquet on the site, and they say nothing about the quantity of the questions, but they do about the quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could write this in Linq in 10 seconds but I think that you are trying to learn fundamental aspects of C# and Linq won't help with that.
Your problem is that you're trying to reach for variables that are in a different method (even though it's static, it doesn't matter). You can add parameters to the findOccurrence method if you need them in that particular scope.

```
private static void findOccurrence(int[] scores, int low, int high)
    { //find the number of times a high/low occurs
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
        {
            if (low == scores[i])
            {
                lowOccurrence++;
                //record number of time slow occurs
            }

            if (high == scores[i])
            {
                highOccurrence++;

                //record number of times high occurs
            }
        }
    }
```

And in findScore() you can call the method above like this:

```
        findOccurrence(scores, low, high);

        if (highOccurrence > 1)
        { //if there is more than 1 high (or 1 low) it is added once into the total
            total += high;

            if (lowOccurrence > 1)
            {
                total += low;
            }
        }
```

I hope this will work as expected. Have fun learning C#

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! this seems to have done the trick! But now I am recieving this error "not all code paths return a value". Now I have fixed this issue with a return value at the end the method, but it doesn't seem like a solid way to program, do you have any tips for that?

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about that, sorry. You can mark your method as void (means it does not return any value). Check my code, I defined the findOccurrence method as void and it does not have to return anything. You can do the same for your findScore method. You can learn how to make new classes if you want to go to the next step of programming. It's an essential thing and you will definitely need it.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I would change my methods to void, but this task requires that "Majority of methods are value returning". I'm just trying to figure out how I can do this right. I also had a followup question regarding your previous answer, I also wanted to put another section of findScore into a new method (that first for loop which records the high/low values) but I am getting a "no overload for method 'findScore' takes 1 arguments. Thanks a bunch for the help

Comment: But `findOccurrence` here doesn't really do anything. If you pass it the `scores` array and two 0's, you'll have gained nothing. The `low` and `high` are scoped to the method and you'll loose them once it's done executing. You need to have them defined globally for your class to access then anywhere within the class.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started :)

You'll need to move `high` and `low` outside of the `findScore` method and initialize with 0 instead of `scores[0]`. Then you'd have to call `findScore` before you call `findOccurrence` to allow the two variables to contain the values you want when you need them.

Also it looks like you come from a Java background. In C# all methods should start with a capital letter, as per naming convention.

You can benefit a lot from Linq. For example you can find `low` with `scores.Min()` and `high` with `scores.Max()`.

`findOccurrence` could be written more briefly:

```
static int FindOccurence(int[] scores)
{
    lowOccurrence = scores.Count(s => s == low);
    highOccurrence = scores.Count(s => s == high);
}
```

Things like this will improve readability to me.

Here's an [Introduction to LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I had solved this using LINQ by in this particular assignment LINQ is not allowed :(